# rosjava_core installation fails

Tags: ros, installation, rosjava-core, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Around one month ago, I installed rosjava_core following the steps presented at the rosjava installation guide (http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/installing.html) without signifcant problems in my desktop computer.

Today, I'm trying to do the same in a different computer (Ubuntu 12.04) but new errors appear. The promblem shows up when merging with remote repository:

```
rosws merge http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/.rosinstall
```

It seems that rosjava_core has been moved (you can check it at http://rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/README) to GitHub (https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core). After surfing this repository, I found a more updated documentation where it is written how to merge with the new remote url:

```
rosws merge https://raw.github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/master/.rosinstall
```

However, I still get the same error when executing it:

```
ERROR in config: Unable to download URL [https://raw.github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/master/.rosinstall]: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

and I can not install it.

What am I doing wrong? how can I solve the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62398/rosjava_core-installation-fails/) by [Álvaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3882/%C3%A1lvaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-05-08

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MorganCormier](https://answers.ros.org/users/360/morgancormier/) on 2013-05-13**:
Did you solve your issue? I am stuck on the same step of the installation.

**Comment by [Álvaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3882/%C3%A1lvaro/) on 2013-05-13**:
I've been able to install rosjava_core in a new machine in a "dirty" way: I copied the files downloaded in a different computer for a previous installation. Then I just followed the steps detailed in the installation guide. I had to install the gradle package in order to avoid a missing dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The answer is here: http://answers.ros.org/question/63403/problem-with-rosjava-installation/?answer=63453#post-id-63453

---

Originally posted by [PJvG](https://answers.ros.org/users/4985/pjvg/) with karma: 31 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0